# DataGridView fail to retrieve stored procedure with temp table

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, stored-procedures, datagridview

I built a stored procedure with two input parameters, wish to fill it into the datatable that my DataGridView bind with.

My Visual Basic code to fill the datatable looks like this:

```
With adSearch.SelectCommand
    .Parameters("trace_txn_no").Value = // Text Value
End With

Me.adSearch.Fill(Me.DsTraceMixPack.trace_rtn_dtl)
```

The stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_RTN_DTL_Trace
    (@trace_txn_no varchar(12),
     @stock_code varchar(8) = '')
AS
BEGIN
    -- Select Data Here
END
```

When I type a single line for selection, such as

```
SELECT
    '00546599' AS mixtxnno, 
    '000000513761' AS txn_no, 
    '81050119' AS stock_code, 
    5 AS qty, 
    '20022' AS to_loc, 
    '2021-09-06' AS txn_date, 
    3 AS onhand_qty, 
    'Department A' AS txn_loc
```

The datagridview works fine.

But when I use a temp table, such as

```
CREATE TABLE #report  
(
    mixtxnno varchar(12),
    txn_no varchar(20),
    stock_code varchar(8),
    qty int,
    to_loc varchar(5),
    txn_date datetime,
    onhand_qty int,
    txn_loc varchar(12)
);

INSERT INTO #report(mixtxnno,txn_no, stock_code,qty, to_loc, txn_date, onhand_qty, txn_loc)
VALUES ('00546599', '000000513761', '81050119', 5, '20022', '2021-09-06', 3, 'Department A')

SELECT 
    mixtxnno AS mixtxnno,
    txn_no AS txn_no,
    stock_code AS stock_code,
    qty AS qty,
    to_loc AS to_loc,
    txn_date AS txn_date,
    onhand_qty AS onhand_qty,
    txn_loc AS txn_loc
FROM
    #report
```

The datagridview stop working, and when I trace the results properties of DataTable 'trace_rtn_dtl', it throws this message

> System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugViewEmptyException

Screenshots:

[image]

Why is this happening and How can I resolve this? I wish to do some manipulation on multiple data and return them to the DataGridView, which I chose to use temp table in my stored procedure. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the Solution

If anyone working with stored procedure not returning Record Set when using temp tables, this might helps.

Add this at the very first in the stored procedure.

`SET NOCOUNT ON`

What seems to happen is that empty RecordSets are generated while manipulating temporary tables, assigning variables etc.

Using "`SET NOCOUNT ON`" prevents these empty sets from being generated, you just need to set it off at the end of the Procedure.